# set_post_thumbnail_size() crop not working

Tags: wordpress, crop

I'm using this code:

```
set_post_thumbnail_size(726, 200, true);
```

My objective is to input any size image and let WP crop it and resize it to 726x200.

I got it working ONE time, just once.
Now it doesn't work anymore. I tried 5 different servers. I tried localhost with xampp and wamp. Nothing!

The image resizes fine but it doesn't get cropped as it should.

I've been looking for answers for the past 5 hours with no luck.
GD is loaded in PHP. I tried different httpd.conf and php.ini tricks and nothing works.
I tried removing the image from the gallery and adding it again as some people suggest and still nothing.

I'm desperate!

Is this a bug?

An image so you can see what's wrong. The image is being resized only but it should be cropped and it should span to the end of the container.
[bad http://tinypic.com/images/404.gif](http://tinypic.com/images/404.gif)
[image: good]

Comment: Where are you doing this? Which file?

Comment: `functions.php` just after `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' )`

Comment: Not sure I understand: How would I *crop* that image so it spans to the end of the container? I don't think that is how the thumbnail mechanism works.

Comment: I put a couple images explaining what's wrong. I got it working ONCE but it doesn't work anymore and I don't know why. I'm using the same exact code. I tried many different images and nothing. The code should do what you see on the second image.

Comment: As said, I'm not sure whether the thumbnail mechanism is capable of doing this. Does it work if you give it an image that is 726 or more pixels wide?

Comment: Nop, That image is 1024 pixels wide. It doesn't work with ANY image.

Comment: OMG, I got it working again. I found the culprit! Yessss! It turns out that I was passing a variable instead of an actual value like this `set_post_thumbnail_size($variable, 200, true)`, but if I pass the actual value like this `set_post_thumbnail_size(726, 200, true)` IT WORKS! Can't believe I just wasted 5 hours...

Comment: Heh! That happens. Nice to hear you got it working.

Comment: I'm guessing that $variable was not of type (int) then, or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG, I got it working again. I found the culprit! Yessss! It turns out that I was passing a variable instead of an actual value like this `set_post_thumbnail_size($variable, 200, true)`, but if I pass the actual value like this `set_post_thumbnail_size(726, 200, true)` IT WORKS! Can't believe I just wasted 5 hours...